# Get the command that generated piped data

Tags: bash, python

I'd like to figure out a way to access a string describing the command that was run before the current command running.

For example, if I run:

```
ls | myscripthere
```

I'd like to be able to know that the "ls" command was the command that generated the output that I am getting via STDIN. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What if there are several, as in `{ echo "Line1" ; echo Line2 ; } | wc -l`

Comment: May we ask why this would be useful to you? Why would you need this information?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm trying to create a command that automatically logs anything written to it. For example, if you run `ls | myscript` it would log: `$ls\nOUTPUTOFLS`.
So, kind of like `tee` but logs the command name as well.

Comment: You're not looking for something like the `script` tool, or the tracing facility that you get from either `set -x` or `set -v`?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a way for a program at the receiving end of a pipe to know what the source of the incoming data are.  Using your example:

```
$ ls | myscript
```

The standard output of `ls` will be redirected to the standard input of `myscript`.  However, this will be entirely indistinguishable from:

```
$ ls > datafile
$ myscript < datafile
```

or

```
$ ls > datafile
$ cat datafile | myscript
```

or

```
$ wget -o - https://www.example.com/some/file/that/resembles/the/output/of/ls | myscript
```

or

```
$ ls | sed '/secrethiddenfile/d' | myscript
```

or even

```
$ cat - | myscript
```

Text is just text.

Comment: Actually that `sed` _is_ distinguishable because you gave it an invalid command, so it exits with _nothing_ on its stdout -- which is myscript's stdin. You probably want `'/secrethidden/d'` or `'s/secrethidden//'`

Comment: Yes, I'm just so used to using the `s` as in  `s/foo/bar/` that I put it in there by reflex.  The point, however, remains; I have corrected the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
echo 'ls' | read var;echo $var > var_file;$var | myscript
```

It will write the value of command in the file `var_file`.

`echo 'ls'` will give `ls` as string input and value of `var` will become `ls`. `$var` will expand into `ls` and will give it's output through pipe to `myscript`.

If you have multiple commands and want to get them line by line in `var_file`, then replace `>` with `>>` i.e.:

```
echo 'ls' | read var;echo $var >> var_file;$var | myscript
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, in general, as:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell

(from the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines)).

If the sending command sticks around long enough, there's a chance you could find it. An example "receiver" script follows; it grabs the NODE column from `lsof` that corresponds to the receiver's stdin, then searches the wider `lsof` output for a process whose stdout NODE matches:

```
#!/bin/sh
# look for f0 and get its node
node=$(lsof -p "$$" -Ffi | awk '/^p/ { node=""; } /^f0$/ { getline; node=substr($0, 2); exit; } END { print node }')

# run lsof and get the pid(s) with f1 whose node match $node
lsof -Ffci | awk -v node="$node" '
  /^c/ { procname=substr($0, 2); }
  /^f1$/ { getline; thisnode=substr($0, 2); }
  /^p/ { if (procname != "" && thisnode == node) { print procname; procname=""; thisnode=""; } }
  END { if (procname != ""&& thisnode == node) print procname; }
  '
cat
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function in my `.bash_aliases` to provide a tee like tool:

```
function teee { 
#This can be used between pipes to print on screen what is coming in from the left command and flows to the next command
        v="$(</dev/stdin)"; 
        echo '---------------- pipe entry-------------' >/dev/tty;
        while read -r l;do 
          echo "$l" >/dev/tty;
        done <<<"$v";
        echo '---------------- pipe exit-------------' >/dev/tty;
        echo "$v"; ##echo to pipe buffer - necessary to keep the data flow to the next command
                }
```

Testing:

```
cat file11
1
2
3
8
9

cat file11 |sed 's/3//' |teee |sed 's/1//'
---------------- pipe entry-------------
1
2

8
9
---------------- pipe exit-------------

2

8
9
```

In your case you can replace all `>/dev/tty` with `>logfile` inside the script.